# Запрос update и проверка в нём

Tags: php, mysql, sql, база-данных, phpmyadmin

Помогите составить `update` - запрос.

Запрос такого типа: обновляем дату в записи *1*, но только если `AND NOW()` больше минимум, на одну минуту, чем дата, которая лежит до запроса в базе. ( Запрос нужен только один, разбивать на несколько запросов и проверок нельзя. )

Пример:

```
mysqli_query($CONNECT, "UPDATE `table` SET `time` = 'NOW()' WHERE `id`= '1' AND
```

Здесь необходимо как-то проверить время, и если данное время больше времени в базе, минимум на одну минуту, то запрос выполняется.

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 3):

```
UPDATE table SET time = NOW()
 WHERE id=1 AND time < DATE_SUB(now(),INTERVAL 1 MINUTE)
```

И не надо в запросе заключать числовые поля типа `id` и тем более имена функций как `now()` в кавычки

Comment: Должно работать, Спасибо! Доберусь до сайта - проверю.

Comment: Спасибо. всё ок. А касаемо скобок на цифры, просто это для примера я цифры вписал, на самом деле там сессии.